# Testing RMI Services

Tags: java, testing, junit, rmi

In a big project with many classes I need test some class that using RMI Service. When I run junit test, my rmi service want other classes, other classes want also some classes and so to infinity. What your suggestions about it? Autowired all that classes long time or I have some alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can pick a point in your framework where you can "mock" the objects.  Then, you can use a framework such as Mockito (http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock out the objects.

This will allow you to simulate results in JUnit, without actually needed the infinite chain of classes you describe.

Note that you will want to test all of it, end to end, at some point.  But for initial development, Mockito will save you the work of all the setup needed.